# To what pins should I connect 4 digits 7 segments display?

Tags: pi-3, display, connection

My display model is: **5641BH** with **common anode**. It have 12 pins. 0.56" THT.

Power range: 5 - 10mA (max 20mA)

I have **Raspberry Pi 3 model B**. + T-Cobbler Plus.

How the hell connect this thing.. In every "tutorial" people doing it diffrent or if there is good detailed article, they says its for common cathode..

Could somebody post a connection scheme of that to RPI3? Does it matter if I connect it for example to "MISO" or other strange named pins instead of "#5, #12"?

And btw. all pins are default 3,3V? - What resistors should I use? R320?

I know that I'm noob, but please help me. :(

Regards and have a nice day!

ps. I want to connect this display with temperature sensor DS18B20.

Comment: I would google the device.  That often leads to schematics showing the connections you need.

Comment: Those segment LEDs usually require some analog inputs and a lot of timing.  You would be better off to spend an extra $2 and get one with an I2C controller.

Comment: Each device is different. It should have a spec sheet somewhere that you'll need to find and use.  Sounds like you haven't found that?  There's no way to guess something like this because there's no requirement that the device follow any particular standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what connections your display uses, but this might help anyway. Pins like MISO, MOSI or CLK work like normal GPIO pins, but they are labeled that way so that people who want to do specific things (like SPI interfacing) know which pins to use for that. Any pin that isn't labeled 3.3V (like pin 1 and pin 17, always on), 5V (pin 2 and pin 4, always on, 5 volts) or GND (ground AKA negative power) works as a normal GPIO pin with regular inputs and outputs. (EDIT: As goldilocks♦ helpfully pointed out, they may behave differently if you have the corresponding bus enabled. To find out if a bus or interface is enabled, go to Preferences -> Raspberry Pi Configuration -> Interfaces.)

As for the temperature sensor, you may need to use an analog to digital converter, because some sensors output using analog signals. One example of a digital to analog converter is the MCP3008 (learn about that [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008)).

***Hope this helps,
Dan :)***

Comment: Beware that the bus pins (like MISO/MOSI, etc) may behave differently when the corresponding bus is enabled.

Comment: I was looking at some other digital displays and how people connect it, and can you tell me why they don't use any of 3,3V or 5V pins? If I turn on normal GPIO pin it have 3,3V or 5V voltage? For temperature sensor I have already solution to get numeric value from it in python, I just need to connect this 7 segment display and display value (displaying with python will be no problem).. im just struggling with connection of that to Raspberry. :(

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Zawodowiec! To clarify, all of the Raspberry Pi's pins other than pins 2 and 4 are 3.3V (3V3). Pins 1 and 17 are always on, and they always output 3.3 volts. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask me! Oh yeah, and thanks to @goldilocks♦ for pointing that detail out to me in the top comment. I've now edited my answer to accommodate that. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

The 3,3V ports may not be powerful enough to drive them! You may have to use transistors to power them through the 5V pins! The transistors can be controlled with the 3,3V GPIO pins. But the power needs to come from the 5V pins.